# Performance degradation of fast-serialization

Tags: java, performance, serialization

This question is particular to the Fast-Serialization library.
https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization

I am using FSTLongOffheapMap (version 2.29) on windows 7, jdk 1.7 to store some objects. I tested the latency of storing an object and the 99.99 percentile comes to about 100 micros. This is **excellent** considering I ran it on windows + didn't write a custom serializer + didn't tune the GC too much.

However, the performance drops sharply if I change the set-up as follows:

a) Create a producer thread and a consumer thread piped by an ArrayBlockingQueue.

b) Let the producer produce 50,000 objects and stuff them in the queue as quickly as possible.

c) The consumer thread pulls out the object, dispatch it to a listener and then store it in the off-heap-map.

In this set-up, the 99.99th percentile latency comes to **~135 millis**!
But the biggest surprise is that if I just comment out the line which performs the put, the latency drops to ~400 micros. This seems illogical to me as I know from the previous test that the latency of a put in the map is only 100 micros.

Below is a test to reproduce my finding, I will appreciate any suggestions/hints/ideas. The only external lib needed to run the test is Gil Tene's HdrHistogram.
https://github.com/HdrHistogram/HdrHistogram

-Thanks so much

---

```
package com.mine.serialization.perf;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.nustaq.offheap.*;
import org.nustaq.serialization.simpleapi.*;

public final class MyFSTSerializer{

    private final boolean toStore;
    private final String fileName;
    private final long memorySize;
    private final FSTCoder fastCoder;
    private final FSTLongOffheapMap<MktDataEvent> offHeapMap;

    public MyFSTSerializer(  boolean toStore, String location, String journalName, FSTCoder fastCoder, long memorySize, int count ) throws Exception{
        this.toStore        = toStore;
        this.fileName       = location + File.separator + journalName + ".mmf";
        this.memorySize     = memorySize;
        this.fastCoder      = fastCoder;
        this.offHeapMap     = new FSTLongOffheapMap<>( fileName, memorySize, count, fastCoder );
    }

    public final boolean toStore( ){
        return toStore;
    }

    public final String getFilename( ){
        return fileName;
    }

    public final void start( ){
        fastCoder.getConf().setCrossPlatform( false );
        fastCoder.getConf().setPreferSpeed( true );
        fastCoder.getConf().setShareReferences( false );
        fastCoder.getConf().registerClass( Long.class, MktDataEvent.class );    
        System.out.println("Journaling started at " + fileName + " with Memory " +  memorySize ) ;
    }

    public final void storeEvent( MktDataEvent event ){
        offHeapMap.put( event.getSequenceId(), event );
    }

    public final Collection<MktDataEvent> retrieveAllEvents( ){
        Map<Long, MktDataEvent> retrievedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for( Iterator<MktDataEvent> iterator = offHeapMap.values(); iterator.hasNext(); ){
            MktDataEvent event = (MktDataEvent) iterator.next();
            retrievedMap.put( event.getSequenceId(), event ); 
         }

        return retrievedMap.values();
    }

    public final void stop( ){
        try{
            offHeapMap.free( );
            System.out.println("Stopped Journal and freed memory." );
        }catch( Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.mine.serialization.perf;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public final class MktDataEvent implements Serializable{

    private final long sequenceId;
    private final long creationTime;
    private final String symbol;
    private final double bidPrice;
    private final long bidQuantity;
    private final double askPrice;
    private final long askQuantity;

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final static AtomicLong SEQUENCE    = new AtomicLong();

    public MktDataEvent( String symbol, double bidPrice, long bidQuantity, double askPrice, long askQuantity ){

        this.creationTime   = System.nanoTime( );
        this.sequenceId     = SEQUENCE.incrementAndGet();
        this.symbol         = symbol;
        this.bidPrice       = bidPrice;
        this.bidQuantity    = bidQuantity;
        this.askPrice       = askPrice;
        this.askQuantity    = askQuantity;
    }       

       public final long getSequenceId( ){
        return sequenceId;
    }

    public final long getCreationTime( ){
        return creationTime;
    }

    public final String getSymbol(){
        return symbol;
    }

    public final double getBidPrice( ){
        return bidPrice;
    }

    public final long getBidQuantity( ){
        return bidQuantity;
    }

    public final double getAskPrice( ){
        return askPrice;
    }

    public final long getAskQuantity( ){
        return askQuantity;
    }
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------

```
package com.mine.serialization.perf;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public final class MktDataDispatcher implements Runnable{

    private volatile boolean keepDispatching;
    private final ExecutorService service;
    private final MyFSTSerializer serializer;
    private final MktDataListener listener;
    private final AbstractQueue<MktDataEvent> eventQueue;

    public MktDataDispatcher( int queueSize, MyFSTSerializer serializer, MktDataListener listener ){
        this.serializer     = serializer;
        this.listener       = listener;
        this.eventQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<MktDataEvent>( queueSize );
        this.service        = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(  1 );
    }

    public final void start( ){
        serializer.start( );
        keepDispatching = true;
        service.execute( this );
    }

    public final boolean enqueue( final MktDataEvent event ){
        return eventQueue.offer( event );
    }

    @Override
    public final void run( ){

        while( keepDispatching ){

            try{
                MktDataEvent event  = eventQueue.poll();
                if( event == null ){
                    Thread.yield();
                    continue;
                }

                if( serializer.toStore() ){
                    serializer.storeEvent( event );
                }
                listener.update( event );

            }catch( Exception e ){
                e.printStackTrace( );                   
            }
            }
        }

    protected final int getQueueSize( ){
        return eventQueue.size( );
    }

    public final void stop(){
        serializer.stop( );
        keepDispatching = false;
        service.shutdown();
    }

    public interface MktDataListener{
        public boolean update( MktDataEvent event );
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.mine.serialization.perf;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import org.HdrHistogram.*;
import org.nustaq.serialization.simpleapi.*;

import com.mine.serialization.perf.MktDataDispatcher.*;



public final class TestFSTSerializer{


    protected static void printResult( Histogram histogram ){
        System.out.println( "\nDetail Result (in micros)");
        System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------------------");

        histogram.outputPercentileDistribution( System.out, 1000.0 );
        double valueAt99Percentile  = histogram.getValueAtPercentile( 99.99d );

        System.out.println( "\nValue 99.99th percentile >> " + valueAt99Percentile/1000.0 );
    }


    protected static MyFSTSerializer createFSTSerializer(  boolean toStore, int eventCount, int memorySizeOf1Object ) throws Exception{

        long expectedMemory     = memorySizeOf1Object * eventCount;
        String fileLocation     = "C:\\Temp";
        String journalName      = "Test";
        MyFSTSerializer ser     = new MyFSTSerializer( toStore, fileLocation, journalName, new DefaultCoder(), expectedMemory, eventCount );

        return ser;
    }


    protected static void destroyFSTSerializer( MyFSTSerializer serializer ){

        if( serializer != null ){
            serializer.stop();
            boolean deleted = new File( serializer.getFilename() ).delete();
            if( deleted ){
                System.out.println( "Deleted file from " +  serializer.getFilename());      
            }else{
                throw new RuntimeException( "TEST FAILED as we failed to delete file " + serializer.getFilename() );
            }
        }

    }


    public static void testOffHeapPersistence( ){

        MyFSTSerializer serializer= null;

        try{

            int eventCount          = 50000;
            int memorySizeOf1Object = 1000;
            Histogram  histogram    = new Histogram( TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 2);

            System.out.println( "Testing off heap persistence performance of FSTLongOffheapMap by storing " + eventCount + " events.");
            serializer              = createFSTSerializer( true, eventCount, memorySizeOf1Object );
            serializer.start( );

            for( int i =0; i<eventCount; i++ ){

                MktDataEvent event = new MktDataEvent( "EDM6", 99.0, (100 + i), 99.50, (200 + i) );
                serializer.storeEvent( event );
                histogram.recordValue(System.nanoTime() - event.getCreationTime() );

            }

            int retrievedEventSize  = serializer.retrieveAllEvents().size();
            if( eventCount != retrievedEventSize )
                throw new RuntimeException("Store failed as we stored " + eventCount + " events but retrieved " + retrievedEventSize );


            printResult( histogram );

        }catch( Exception e ){
            throw new RuntimeException("TEST FAILED as ", e);

        }finally{
            destroyFSTSerializer( serializer );
        }

    }



    public static void testDispatchAndPersistence( boolean toStore ) throws Exception{

        int eventCount                  = 50000;
        int memorySizeOf1Object         = 1000;

        DummyListener listener          = new DummyListener( );
        MyFSTSerializer serializer      = createFSTSerializer( toStore, eventCount, memorySizeOf1Object );
        MktDataDispatcher dispatcher    = new MktDataDispatcher( eventCount, serializer, listener );

        if( toStore ){
            System.out.println( "Testing off heap persistence with dispathcer performance of FSTLongOffheapMap by storing " + eventCount + " events."); 
        }else{
            System.out.println( "Testing off heap persistence with dispathcer performance of FSTLongOffheapMap WITHOUT storing " + eventCount + " events.");
        }

        dispatcher.start();
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep( 3000 );

        for( int i = 0; i< eventCount; i++ ){
            MktDataEvent event = new MktDataEvent( "EDM6", 99.0, (100 + i), 99.50, (200 + i) );
            dispatcher.enqueue( event );
        }

        //Let the listener get all the elements
        while( (dispatcher.getQueueSize() != 0) ){
            Thread.yield();
        }

        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        dispatcher.stop();
        listener.generateLatencyStats();
        destroyFSTSerializer( serializer );

    }


    public static class DummyListener implements MktDataListener{

        private final Histogram histogram;

        public DummyListener( ){
            this.histogram  = new Histogram( TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), 2);
        }


        @Override
        public final boolean update( MktDataEvent event ){
            histogram.recordValue( (System.nanoTime() - event.getCreationTime()) );
            return true;
        }


        public final void generateLatencyStats( ){

            histogram.outputPercentileDistribution( System.out, 1000.0 );
            double valueAt99Percentile  = histogram.getValueAtPercentile( 99.99d );
            System.out.println( "\nValue at 99.99th percentile (micros) >> " + valueAt99Percentile/1000.0 );

        }

    }

    public static void main( String ... args ) throws Exception{

        testOffHeapPersistence( );

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        testDispatchAndPersistence( false );

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        testDispatchAndPersistence( true );

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you can put your code in steps, like  first the code in the "excellent" stage, and then the change, and so on.. we don't need the entire code, but maybe just the suspicious snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi (i am author of FST):

I think the test is flawed:

When running your sync (no queues + thread context switches) test in a loop (=proper warmup) I get a Mean of **0.7 micros** and **Max outlier of 14 micros** (doubled number of elements in map though) storing a single event.
  This is the performance of FST, the loss and latency you see is caused by your queuing/thread context switches. In addition the test has a flaw:

*You put a burst of 50k events into a queue taking time on Event creation. As putting events is much faster than than storing events, you get accumulation: N'th event gets the latency of all 0..n-1 events accumulated ;).*

It seems to be good in the first run due to missing JVM warm up: event creation is slow then so events get not queued up.

**Other issues:**

1) Major: NO WARMUP. put a loop and let the test run several times (like 10) before looking at the numbers.

2) (minor) Enqueing is done via offer without checking result

3) you poll the queue doing a yield if no event is avaiable, this can lead to indeterministic latency spikes. Do the yield only after some backoff.

You should put an event into the queue each ~1-2 microsecond to avoid queuing up events and measuring aggregated times this way.

change TestFSTSerializer to:

```
    for( int i = 0; i< eventCount; i++ ){
        MktDataEvent event = new MktDataEvent( "EDM6", 99.0, (100 + i), 99.50, (200 + i) );
        dispatcher.enqueue( event );
        long nanos = System.nanoTime();
        while( System.nanoTime() - nanos < 3000 )
            Thread.yield();

    }
```

and main method (warmup, ignore first runs):

```
public static void main( String ... args ) throws Exception{

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep( 2000 );
        System.out.println("start test ==>");
        testDispatchAndPersistence( true );
        //testOffHeapPersistence();
    }
```

yields:

[Mean    =         5.19, StdDeviation   =        29.67]

[Max     =       544.77, Total count    =        50000]

[Buckets =           23, SubBuckets     =          256]

Note that thread context switches cost you 3-8 microseconds (so high end kernel bypassed network's can be nearly as fast as queuing between threads !!).
You could try to use faster queues than java.concurrent ones to further reduce latency.

Note for later testing: as persistence relies on OS writeback eagerness, you need to tweak OS settings to writeback very un-eager and/or use SSD.

see https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization/tree/master/src/test/ser/offheaplatency for modified source

Comment: Hi Ruediger, thanks very much for taking a look so quickly and of course for all the suggestions. Let me ponder over them, may bug you again if I have any other questions. Thanks once again, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the tricks I use to improve performance of maps is to provide an initial capacity to them. 
What I mean is that your LinkedHashMap should be initialized with a capacity that is around the order of number of events

 you expect to push prior to retrieval.